# Computing an integral related to a unique zero of $ze^z-w$

Tags: complex-analysis

I proved that the equation $ze^z=w$ for $w\in D(0,1/e),z\in D(0,1)$ has a unique solution using Rouché's Theorem noted $h(w)$.

Now the goal is to prove that $h(w)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}w^n.$

I succeed to prove that if $a_n:=\int_{\partial D(0,1)}(1-z)z^{-n}e^{nz}dz=\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}$ using Cauchy integral formula,

and **if** $$\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{z(z-1)e^{-z}}{ze^{-z}-w}dz=h(w)$$ then it follow by interchanging "integrals and series".

Now I would like to prove this, I was trying to using Kronecker's formula but I have $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\times z:=g(z).$ So I tried Residue theorem to the meromorphic function $g(z).$ As there is a unique pole $h(w)$ it follow directly by the theorem if $$Res(g,h(w))=h(w).$$

I don't see how it's true ?

Comment: This sort of problem can also be done by the Lagrange inversion theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F$ is holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $z_0$ and $F$ has a zero of multiplicity $m$ at $z_0$, we can write

$$F(z) = (z-z_0)^m\cdot G(z)\tag{1}$$

with $G$ holomorphic on the same neighbourhood of $z_0$ as $F$, and $G(z_0) \neq 0$. Using the representation $(1)$ to compute $F'/F$, we find that - for $z$ such that $F(z)\neq 0$ - we have

$$\frac{F'(z)}{F(z)} = \frac{m(z-z_0)^{m-1}G(z) + (z-z_0)^mG'(z)}{(z-z_0)^mG(z)} = \frac{m}{z-z_0} + \frac{G'(z)}{G(z)}.\tag{2}$$

Since $G$ doesn't vanish on some (possibly smaller than the original) neighbourhood of $z_0$, the term $\frac{G'(z)}{G(z)}$ is holomorphic at $z_0$. Multiplying $(2)$ with $z = z_0 + (z-z_0)$ we find

$$\frac{zF'(z)}{F(z)} = \frac{mz}{z-z_0} + \frac{zG'(z)}{G(z)} = \frac{mz_0}{z-z_0} + m + \frac{zG'(z)}{G(z)},$$

from which we can read off that the residue of $\frac{zF'(z)}{F(z)}$ at $z_0$ is $mz_0$.

In your case, we have $m = 1$, and $z_0 = h(w)$.

Comment: arf!!! I tried to do it, but I get $mz/z-h(w)$ and get blocked... Nice:D.